# Hi, i am doing ajax call using jquery for post method. I am able to insert data to database but the sucess msg or error message is not reflected

Tags: jquery

i am doing ajax call using jquery for post method. I am able to insert data to database but the sucess msg or error message is not reflected.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url",
    data: employee,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
       alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please show your server side? maybe problem is, that mysql query is returning true if succeed, so it will not show with simple echo

Comment: what you are sending from your backend code to ajax..?

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the response in your alert in success function, you're saying the success message is not defined it could be because your return type of url is void. Try with alert("Custom text") once!